# In Mac OS X, how can I edit a jar file without unzipping?

Tags: macos, zip

How can I edit the content of a jar file without unzipping its content in Mac OS X?

7z client allows this on windows but I could not find a similar way to do this on Max OSX.

By editing i really mean deleting files or directories, moving files around, etc.

Answer (score 9):

On Mac OS X terminal you can use emacs to edit files within a jar. Just type:

```
emacs somejar.jar
```

You can then browse all the files in the jar, open, save, whatever using standard emacs commands. Any changes you make will automatically be applied to the jar (no need to manually unjar anything).

Comment: Thanks, as far as I have seen you can edit the files in the jar themselves. You cannot though move directories and delete files, or I am mistaken here?

Comment: I would check the emacs command list here, specifically the 'directory editor' section: http://lpn.rnbhq.org/tools/xemacs/emacs_ref.html

Comment: Also possible with vim: `vim somejar.jar`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a graphical program iUnarchive it a good tool. It does cost some money though.

http://www.iunarchive.com/